# Checkbox column not getting checked in datagridview c#

Tags: c#, checkbox, datagridview

I have added checkbox column in datagridview and i want that checkboxes checked if one of my column value == 1 otherwise the checkbox should be unchecked
i have written following code where content loads in datagridview and that method is called at form load event
but checkboxes not showing checked when first time that method is calling when method gets called second time that is working correct

```
DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn chkboxcolumn = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
chkboxcolumn.HeaderText = "";
chkboxcolumn.Width = 30;
chkboxcolumn.Name = "checkBoxColumn";

      if (!dgvCompany.Columns.Contains(chkboxcolumn.Name))
      {
            dgvCompany.Columns.Insert(0, chkboxcolumn);
      }
               
      for (int i = 0; i < dgvCompany.Rows.Count; i++)
      {
            if (Convert.ToString (dgvCompany.Rows[i].Cells["CompanyLead"].Value) == "1")
            {
                   dgvCompany.Rows[i].Cells["checkBoxColumn"].Value = true;
                        
            }
      }
```

Comment: What is the column type of the `CompanyLead` column? How is the code adding the data to the grid? You could simplify this greatly if the grid used a `DataTable` as a `DataSource`... But it is unknown how the data is put into the grid.

Comment: Dataset ds = FunctionalClass.ExecuteStoredProcedureWithParameters(Para, "Fill_CompanyDetails_Preview");
                
                if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
                {
                    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        dgvCompany.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];   }    }

Comment: What is the "CompanyLead" column type in the `ds.Tables[0]` ... ? ...

Answer (score 0):

Try to change:

```
dgvCompany.Rows[i].Cells["checkBoxColumn"].Value =  true;
```

to:

```
dgvCompany.Rows[i].Cells["checkBoxColumn"].Checked =  true;
```

if the checked not appear in the IDE, try to cast this cell to a checkbox

```
var test = (Checkbox)dgvCompany.Rows[i].Cells["checkBoxColumn"];
test.Checked = true;
```

Comment: var test =(CheckBox)dgvCompany.Rows[i].Cells["checkBoxColumn"]; Or var test =(CheckBox)dgvCompany.Rows[i].Cells["checkBoxColumn"].value; ? if var test =(CheckBox)dgvCompany.Rows[i].Cells["checkBoxColumn"].value then its giving null value exception  because the value in the checkbox column is null

Comment: var test = (CheckBox)dgvCompany.Rows[i].Cells["checkBoxColumn"];

Comment: (CheckBox)dgvCompany.Rows[i].Cells["checkBoxColumn"].value the value é not convertible

Comment: var test=(CheckBox)dgvCompany.Rows[i].Cells["checkBoxColumn"]; 
says cannot convert  system.windows.form.DatagridViewCell to System.Windows.Forms.Checkbox

Comment: var test=(CheckBox)dgvCompany.Rows[i].Cells["checkBoxColumn"]; says cannot convert system.windows.form.DatagridViewCell to System.Windows.Forms.Checkbox

Comment: I mean no disrespect and am only trying to help. However, your answer is not going to help anyone. One: `DataGridView` Cells do NOT have a `Checked` property like… `dgvCompany.Rows[i].Cells["checkBoxColumn"].Checked =  true;` … even if the cell is a `CheckBoxCell`. Also, Two: you CAN NOT simply cast a `DataGridView` Cell to a regular `CheckBox` like… `var test = (Checkbox)dgvCompany.Rows[i].Cells["checkBoxColumn"];` … even if the cell is a check box cell. You may want to re-think how your answer helps the OP or anyone for that matter since the info is simply wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Is what I am getting at is that if the grids `DataSource` is a `DataTable` AND the `CompanyLead` column in the data table is of a `string` type, then simply add the code below to add a `bool` “Expression” column to the existing table. [DataColumn.Expression Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=net-6.0)

With this, then ALL the posted code you have shown becomes unnecessary. Something like…

```
ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add("CheckBoxColumn", typeof(bool), "IIF(CompanyLead = 1, true, false)");
```

Comment: It worked Thanks and i added display index to bring that column at beginning

Comment: As i use that column as bool type it is read only what should i need to do to make it read only=false 
i tried  dgvCompany.Columns["checkBoxColumn"].ReadOnly = false; but its not usefull for bool type 
My CompanyLead Column datatype is int in DB

Comment: The “expression” columns are not editable and why would they be? Its value (checked or unchecked) is dependent on what value “CompanyLead” is. If you change the CompanyLead value, then that is how you change the check box expression cells value. You could also, bind the check box column to the “CompanyLead” field. What “different” values does the “CompanyLead” have?